# Visual Studio 2012 Play button displaying the word Attach

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How do I remove the word attach... at the play button in Visual Studio? I do not know what I did to change the settings.

Comment: why do you want to remove it? do you mean how do you get the play button to debug your project? open a project you can start from and it will go away. if this is not the case then stick a piece of duct tape over it on your screen, because you do not understand why it is there and should not be harassed by it any more

Comment: What project type are you using? This should only show the word 'Attach' when the project is loading... Search using Google for other people having the same issue... You might need to set a start up project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click a runnable project (console, web application, winforms) in your solution and select "Set as Startup Project".

Comment: When I right click a runnable project I do not get that option.

Answer (score 0):

Just see that your application name do not have any space.
example: lets assume that your application name is "airline reservation".
As you can see that there is space between airline and reservation. Remove the spacing in your application name and then save it. You will have the play button back in position.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably opened a dtsx file (File -> Recent Files -> .dtsx) in stead of opening a project.

Answer (score 0):

in launchSettings.json you have "profiles", change the name in there and the name in button will be change